# How to maintain integrity?

Tags: rdbms

I am just curious how do you all create tables to maintain integrity?

```
tblUserProfile

UserId
EyeColorId
HairColorId
RelationShipStatusId
```

etc.

Each of these values like EyeColorId has a set of values like Brown,Black,Yellow,Green. Similary HairColorId has black, blonde, crimson etc and RelationShipStatusId has Divorced, Married, Single etc. Should i create different tables for each one of these? like

```
tblEyeColor

EyeColorId
EyeColorCode
```

then :-

```
tblHairColor

HairColorId
HairColorCode
```

and likewise keep creating tables? There are many such tables(approximately 20-25). If i keep creating these tables and make joins on them, it will terribly slow down my performance. How do you all maintain this sort of enum values? Should i keep a check constraint or should i keep making tables?

Comment: no need for tables, all modern RDBMS system worth using have the ability to put 'check constraints' on a column

Comment: Hi lolli, Check constraint is a good idea. But just imagine what would happen if for example i keep check constraint on column to be any value from {Brown,Black,Hazel}. Let us say, now i want to change the constraint and make it {Brown,Black,Yellow}. This would lead to a problem. Won't it? For example, if the table contains eye color with value Hazel, it will not allow me to create new constraints saying that "few rows contains Hazel as value" and this would lead to severe maintainance problem if there are lacs of entries. This is a simple case but still i will have to fire update queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that Color looks like it could be a single table that both hair and eye could both use.  How important is it to your integrity to enforce the fact that no one should have blonde eyes or blue hair?

Some people go with the idea of a single lookup table, which would have an id, a group, and a value and perhaps a description for each row.  The id and group would be the primary key, so you'd have id = 1 and group = 1 for hair as the BLONDE hair color, id = 1 and group = 2 for eyes as the HAZEL eye color, etc.

Others would deride this as a poor denormalized design.

The joins will only slow you down when the number for a particular query gets large.

My advice would be to do a normalized design until you have some data to suggest that it's performing poorly.  When that happens, profile your app to find out where the problem is and refactor or denormalize appropriately.

I would say that indexing will have a greater impact on your performance than these JOINs.  You might be guilty of premature optimization without data to support it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need of creating tables if the number of options are `fixed` You can use `Enum` Type instead in your table.
e.g. Column `EyeColor` will be Enum of `Black, Brown, Blue`

However I've never seen someone with Green Eyes. LOL

Comment: What is enum type? There is no such data type atleast in Sql Server or MySql?

Comment: I donno SqlServer However in MySQL there is Enum See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/enum.html in PostgreSql too You can use Enum Functionality http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-enum.html

Enums might be handled in any different ways in database Internals. But That does not not a matter in this regard

Comment: "However I've never seen someone with Green Eyes. LOL"  Really?  It's not uncommon in some places.

Answer (score 1):

That is the traditional method, yes.

Most modern RDBMSs will cache small tables like these lookups for extended periods of time, which alleviates the potential multi-join issues.

Also, you could pre-load all of the lookup tables in your application, and reverse-convert the enums to ids in code before accessing the database.  This way you won't need joins in your queries.